# Prove that if $q_i$'s are polynomials of degree $i$,then $q_1,...,q_n$ are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $q_i$'s are polynomials of degree $i$,then $q_0,...,q_n$ are linearly independent.

---

Assume they are not linearly independent, so there is a scalar $\lambda_m \ne 0$ with $0\le m\le n$ such that $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\lambda_iq_{i}\left(x\right)=0$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_m}q_{i}\left(x\right)=0$$

How to get a contradiction?

Comment: Try to first do the case $n=1$. Once you understand that one, you should also get the general case.

Comment: This is not even a try, it is merely writing out the definition of linear independence that you have to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose some $\lambda_i$ is not $0$. There is a largest integer $m \leq n$ such that $\lambda_m \neq 0$ and $\lambda_k=0$ for $ k>m$. [$m$ could be equal to $n$]. Now look at the coefficient of $x^{m}$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: $\lambda_m a$ must be $0$ and $a \neq 0$ so we get $\lambda_m=0$. This is a contradction. @masaheb

Comment: If a polynomial is $0$ then all its coefficients must be $0$. In particular the coefficient of $x^{m}$ must be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

As the matrix of coefficients is triangular with a nonzero diagonal, you can reduce to canonical polynomials by Gaussian elimination. And the canonical basis $is$ of course made of independent vectors. (Note that as $q_0$ is not included, the $q_i$ do not form a basis for polynomials of degree $n$.)